# MPDF creates damaged PDF

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

Simple "hello world" code doesn't work! Generates long pdf that no program can't open. Tried few different versions of mpdf

Tried removing the line with "hello world" - getting blank readable pdf without any text

```
include("../mpdf_new/vendor/autoload.php");
$mpdf=new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('Hello World');
$mpdf->Output();
```

PDF is generated, no extra symbols; but can't be opened.

Comment: Condolences. What is your question? Try sharing the unreadable PDF, that'd help in assesing this behaviour.